# MultiValueDictKeyError error in Django during using Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, django-views

I am trying to learn Ajax technology the hard way. so, I created following part of my HTML:

## In HTML:

```
<form id="form_{{ i }}_{{ j }}" action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button class="ui green button" name="csrfmiddlewaretoken" value="{{ csrf_token }}" id="enroll_{{ i }}_{{ j }}" >Enroll</button>
</form>
```

## In  JS:

```
$(function(){
        $('button[id^="enroll"]').each(function(){
            $(this).mouseup(function(){
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "/",
                    data: {
                        'course': $(this).parents('div[id^="description_"]').find('a[id^="link_"]').text(),
                        'csrfmiddlewaretoken': $('button[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val()

                    },
                    success: courseFinder($(this)),
                    dataType: 'text',
                    error: function(req, err){ alert('my message' + err); }
                });
            });
        });
    });

    function courseFinder(data, textStatus, jqXHR, it){
        it.parents('form[id^="form_"]').attr()
    }
});
```

## In view:

```
def homepage(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        if request.method == "POST":
            course = request.POST['course']
            courses = Course.objects.get(course_title=course)
        level = get_list_or_404(Level, level_hardiness="Beginner")
        level_ids = [sets.id for sets in level]
        courses = Course.objects.filter(course_level__in=level_ids)
        send = {'level': level, 'courses': courses,}
        return render(request, "Moolak/homepage.html", send)
    else:
        return render(request, "main/home_page.html", {'date': date.today()})
```

But it return `MultiValueDictKeyError` in  `course = request.POST['course']`

It's my another question: Is it necessary to use input?
Any helps are welcome! THANKS.

Comment: your view function is specific for this ajax request or it also handles non ajax  requests?

Comment: I think both of them!

Comment: You need to show your whole form...there's no `<input>` with `name="course"` in your HTML above

Comment: also show the whole view :D

Comment: `request.POST.get('course','')` would eliminate the error and your `course` var will contain empty string if `course` is not found in post data.